# Ruby library to parse strings into the appropriate data type Google Sheets-style

Tags: ruby, parsing

I want to parse a Ruby string into the data type it represents in the same way that Google Sheets does this.

E.g., when you type "hello" into a Google Sheet it's interpreted as a string. "100" as a number, "$100" as a currency, etc.

More examples:

- The string "Jan 1, 2001" should turn into a date.
- The string "true" should turn into a boolean.

What's the best way to accomplish this without manually writing a regex-driven case statement?

Comment: "The string 'true' should turn into a boolean." Would `false` be OK? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This seems like an X/Y problem. If your real question is about how to serialize arbitrary Ruby values, than the answer is very different. As it stands, there is an unbounded list of possible input strings here. You need to specify the set of types you want to handle. Should `"[1, 2]"` and `"{foo: 'bar'}"` return an array and a hash? What about `"2017/01/01" and "01/01/2017"`? What about `"John Smith"`?

Comment: @meagar I updated the question to represent my intent: parsing user input as if the user were entering it into a "smart" spreadsheet like Google Sheets. I think Excel also does some version of this input interpretation. Does this make sense?

Comment: This is still either too broad, or a request for a library. Ruby's type system cannot represent all the data types of Google Sheets, there is no simple or canonical way of doing what you want in Ruby.

Comment: Tom, to meet @meagar's objection I suggest you edit to list, for each class of interest, one or more example strings that are to be converted to an instance of that class. For example, for the class `Float` you might list `"-4.3"`, `"2.0"` and `"1.03e2"`, for `BigDecimal`, `"0.123e3"`, and so on.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I don't think this question is on-topic here, period. Reproducing all of the types of Google Sheets is out of scope for a single SO question. Ruby has no currency type, or duration type, or percent type, or several others. Parsing arbitrary inputs into a hypothetical Google Sheets type system for Ruby is too broad a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @meagar, if what you describe (ref. Goggle Sheets)--which the OP introduced in the edit--how could I disagree? If, however, the OP edited as I suggested I don't see a problem, though I don't see how it would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

The possible date formats must be specified. Were one to use [Date#parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse), the string `"Theresa May has announced she will resign"` would return `#<Date: 2019-05-01 ((2458605j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`.

Here's a start.

```
require 'date'
require 'bigdecimal'

def my_class(str)
  return true if str == 'true'
  return false if str == 'false'
  return nil if str == 'nil'
  date = DateTime.strptime(str, '%b %d, %Y') rescue nil
  return date unless date.nil?
  return BigDecimal(str) if str.match?(/\A-?0.\d+e\d+\z/i)
  n = Float(str) rescue nil
  return n if n && str.include?('.')
  n = Integer(str) rescue nil
  return n unless n.nil?
  raise ArgumentError
end
```

```
my_class 'true'    #=> true 
my_class 'false'   #=> true 
my_class 'nil'     #=> nil 
my_class '-32'     #=> -32 
my_class '0'       #=> 0
my_class '1.0'     #=> 1.0 
my_class '-1.03'   #=> -1.03 
my_class '1.02e-2' #=> 0.0102
my_class '-1.99E2' #=> -199.0
my_class '-0.99e1' #=> -0.99e1 (BigDecimal)
my_class '-0.99E1' #=> -0.99e1 (BigDecimal)
my_class '0.0'     #=> 0.0
my_class 'Jan 1, 2001'
  #=> #<DateTime: 2001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2451911j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
my_class 'January 1, 2001'
  #=> #<DateTime: 2001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2451911j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
my_class 'January 32, 2001'
  #=> nil
```

Except for `str = "0.0"`, the return value for a string converted to a `BigDecimal`, then converted back to a string matches the pattern

```
r = /\A-?0\.\d+e\d+\z/
```

(e.g. `BigDecimal("123.4").to_s #=> "0.1234e3"`). By contrast a string representing a float in scientific notation customarily matches the pattern

```
/\A-?[1-9]\.\d+e\d+\z/
```

I therefore assumed that a string matches a `BigDecimal` if and only if it matches `r` (though I've made `r` case-indifferent so that, for example, `"0.12E2"` will be regarded as a `BigDecimal`).

Comment: Pardon what might be a basic question, but would it need to determine if it is a `Float` or a `BigDecimal`? Wouldn't that be dependent on if they were going to do some calculation? Could they just assume `Float` and convert if they needed precise calculation?

Comment: @Beartech, I've done an edit that changes the criterion for determining if a string is a representation of a `BigDecimal`. You have a point, but the question specifically asks for a determination of whether a string is a representation of a `BigDecimal` as opposed to whether a string can be converted to a `BigDecimal`.